Project Build is failed due to CentralPackageVersions
I have opened new project in Visual Studio Code IDE but when I tried to Build the project ,it throws the below error.
I tried multiple ways but no luck for me.
Can any one help me on this?.
D:\Project_ddots\ddots\src\dDots.Web\dDots.Web.csproj : error : Could not resolve SDK "Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions". Exactly one of the probing messa
ges below indicates why we could not resolve the SDK. Investigate and resolve that message to correctly specify the SDK.
D:\Project_ddots\ddots\src\dDots.Web\dDots.Web.csproj : error :   SDK resolver "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildWorkloadSdkResolver" returned null.
D:\Project_ddots\ddots\src\dDots.Web\dDots.Web.csproj : error :   Unable to find package Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions. No packages exist with this id
in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
D:\Project_ddots\ddots\src\dDots.Web\dDots.Web.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions/2.1.3' specified could not be found.
Error Screenshot
